Why race condition occurs when hardware has ensured coherency
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std::chrono;

const int nthreads = 4;
const int64_t ndata = 1600000;

int total_sum = 0;

void compute_sum(int tid, std::vector<int>& d)
{
  int st = (ndata / nthreads) * tid;
  int en = (ndata / nthreads) * (tid + 1);
  for (int i = st; i < en; i++) {
    total_sum += d[i];
  }
}

int main(int argc, char ** arg)
{
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  
  std::vector<int> data;
  for (int i = 0; i < ndata; i++) {
    data.push_back(i);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
    threads.push_back(std::thread(compute_sum, i, std::ref(data)));
  }
  
  for (auto &th : threads) {
    th.join();
  }
  return 0;
}


Here total_sum is shared between two threads, thus race condition occurs and this code is messed up (until atomics or locks are used).
But when hardware level coherency is implemented like MESI protocol, shouldn't the shared memory be handled properly by the hardware itself such that no race condition occurs?

C++ doesn't care about the underlying machine.  C++ defines an abstract machine and your code must compile to the rules of that machine.  One of those rules is more than one thread cannot modify a shared variable unless you have synchronization.  To not do so introduces a data race and undefined behavior.

So just use an atomic<int> and trust the implementation to do what is absolutely minimum required to make the updates atomic. I'm sure the library implementor is also aware of MESI.

You are assuming that total_sum += d[i] means that, in exactly the source code order, the compiler will emit one single instruction that loads, adds and then stores the value of total_sum from/to memory. But when you write in a high-level language like C++, the code that you write does not have any such correspondence. There is no reason that the compiler ought to compile it exactly like this. It is for example much more reasonable (and permitted according to the rules of the abstract machine) to keep total_sum in a register, so that the hardware cache behavior won't matter at all.

Also (all of the above plus) with the absence of memory fences the optimizer is allow to modify the code as if it only has one thread of execution.

The MESI protocol (Wikipedia) is a mechanism which improves the performance of maintaining the coherence of a CPU Cache.
A CPU Cache (Wikipedia) is a hardware component which lies between the CPU and the main memory of a computer.
The coherence of the CPU cache is completely unrelated to the thread-safety of:

your code, or
collections such as std::vector<> that your code might use, or
anything whatsoever that you might do in C++, or
anything whatsoever that you might even do in machine code, which is what C++ compiles to.

In other words, one has absolutely nothing to do with the other.
Knowledge of the existence of the CPU cache and of its inner workings is only helpful to expert programmers as a means of writing code that will perform more optimally by taking into account peculiarities about the way the cache works.  (For example, when iterating over all elements of a two-dimensional array declared as Array[Y][X], you will usually get better performance if your outer loop iterates along Y, and your inner loop iterates along X.)

What I assumed was as follows, "Suppose the processor has two cores and thread 1 is being run on core 1 and thread 2 is being run on core 2. Lets say initially total_sum is fetched from memory and accessed by thread 1 and then written back and then accessed by thread 2 etc. Doesn't the coherence protocols take care of this synchronisation". This is what I meant when I asked the question. I have no idea about the answer you have given :(

Each thread will not have a designated core all the time. The scheduler of the operating system will keep re-assigning the threads to various cores all the time.

total_sum will not necessarily be written back; as others have pointed out, it may be kept in a register.  You have to declare it volatile, or take care of synchronization programmatically, for that to happen.

If and when total_sum eventually gets written back to memory, and if it is written in a cache which is not shared among cores, (some caches are shared among cores in some architectures,) then the coherence protocols will make sure that it will be seen by the right core that needs to read it, but again, there is nothing you can do to either facilitate or prevent this from C++, and therefore you do not care about this as a C++ programmer.

This is like worrying about quantum interactions when all you are trying to do is play football.  Yes, of course, at a low level, it all boils down to quantum interactions, but there is absolutely no use in thinking in terms of quanta when playing football; plain simple Newtonian mechanics will do.  You do not care about quantum mechanics when playing football, and there is no knowledge of quantum mechanics that will either improve, or ruin, your football game.

To put it in different words, there was a time when CPUs had no L1, L2, L3 cache, and there were no coherence protocols in place, and our software worked.  Then one day CPU manufacturers introduced CPU caches. This did not require rewriting any software: everything that used to work continued working, and everything that used to be buggy continued to be just as buggy.

Thanksss!!!!. It is not that I am thinking in terms of quantum interactions, just wanted to know why does race condition even occurs here. (My professor induced this idea in class). Anyways, I'm Satisfied with the answer.

The big gap between the c++ abstract machine and the physical hardware is that without atomics or memory fences, the abstract machine is allowed to assume that the variables aren't seen from anything except the current thread. That means that the compiler is allowed to generate code that reads total_sum into a register, do all of the summing operations on that register, and then commit the value back to memory after the loop.
When that happens, all of the other writes that may have happened to the memory between the read and when it was written back are not seen/are over written.
Once you add atomics, the operations need to always operate on the memory and be globally visible as soon as they happen. If you add mutexes or other locking, then the threads must commit their results back to memory before releasing the lock and must read from memory after the lock is acquired, forcing a globally consistent sequence of operations.
Just because the hardware has instructions and protocols that handle things doesn't mean the compiler generates code that exercises those mechanisms unless it needs to based on the language features in use.
